# How to pass the return value of a command function of a button as input of a command function of another button

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am new in tkinter please help me out . I have implemented a module(PDF2Text.Py) that its class has a function (convert_pdf_to_txt(path)) that takes a path of a pdf file and converts the pdf file into text.

I also implemented another module(TopicModeling.py) that its class has a function (creat_LDA_model(text)) that takes a text and do topic modeling on the text.

Now, I want the tkinter GUI that is, upon clicking the "Browse" button it browses the path with filedialog.askopenfilename and its command function sends the given path to convert_pdf_to_txt(path) function of PDF2Text.Py.

Then by clicking the "Model" button, its command function get the text and send it creat_LDA_model(text) function in TopicModeling.py and show the result in an Entry widget or any other widget types .

I would like to know the structure of the GUI module; how to call or get and set the parameters to other modules/functions from the GUI module in command functions of the buttons.

let me explain more:

suppose this is my code:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import filedialog
import TopicModeling
import Pdf2Text

window = tkinter.Tk()
window.title("Welcome to test tkinter app")
window.geometry('750x600')# Setting Window Size

lbl = tkinter.Label(window, text="Select a pdf file:", font=("Arial Bold", 15))#Set Label Font Size
lbl.grid(column=0, row=0)#set its position on the form



def Return_pdfText():
          filename =  filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes = (("pdf files","*.pdf"),("all files","*.*")))    
         mytext = Pdf2Text.Pdf2Text(filename)   
         PdfText=mytext.convert_pdf_to_txt(filename)
         return PdfText

Button=tkinter.Button(window,text="Browse",command=Return_pdfText)
Button.grid(column=0, row=1)

window.mainloop()
```

I want to put another button,namely 'Model'.   its command function should get the pdfText as input and model it ,like this:

```
Button=tkinter.Button(window,text="Model",command=Model)
Button.grid(column=1, row=1)

def Model(pdfText): #??
    my_LDA_model= TopicModeling.TopicModeling(PdfText)
   model=my_LDA_model.create_lda_model()
   my_LDA_model.WordCloud_topics(model)
   ...????
```

the result (topics and the graphs) should be shown in the GUI in some widgets.

My problem is about this command function. how to pass pdfText to model function, how show the results, and in which type of widgets?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you have a small program the simplest way is to use global variables for shared data:

```
def Return_pdfText():
    global PdfText  # Put the variable in the global scope
    filename =  filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes = (("pdf files","*.pdf"),("all files","*.*")))    
    mytext = Pdf2Text.Pdf2Text(filename)   
    PdfText = mytext.convert_pdf_to_txt(filename)   # Assign to global variable
```

After `PdfText` is assigned a value it will be available for the `Model()` function and you don't need to pass it:

```
def Model():
    my_LDA_model = TopicModeling.TopicModeling(PdfText)
    model = my_LDA_model.create_lda_model()
    my_LDA_model.WordCloud_topics(model)
```

Comment: thanks, it works.   and in which type of widgets I can show the created graphs?

Comment: I'm not into topic modelling so I don't know what kind of objects are created. But in general; for text use a `Text()` widget, for images use a `Canvas()` widget or if you just want to display it a `Label()` widget.